# List of list in Scala accessing a block

Tags: scala, collections, block

I have a list of lists which represent a grid. I need to access elements of a particular block. For example given:

```
| 0 | 1 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 8 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 || 2 | 9 | 0 || 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 || 7 | 0 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 0 |
 -------------------------------------
| 0 | 4 | 0 || 5 | 0 | 0 || 7 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 || 4 | 6 | 0 || 9 | 8 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 || 1 | 0 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 0 |
 -------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 0 || 5 | 0 | 0 || 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 || 0 | 1 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 9 | 0 || 3 | 0 | 0 || 0 | 0 | 4 |
```

Given block (0) should return List(1), Given block (5) should return List (7,8,9,1,2)

My attempt:

```
((grid.grouped(3).toList(block / 3).map(_.grouped(3).toList(block % 3)))flatten)
```

and it works but I need to find a simpler way without all these collections

Comment: Which collections? Intermediate ones from your solution? Or the original storage of the List?

Comment: like map , grouped , flatten

Comment: Generally speaking, those are pretty fast operations in scala. I would not try to avoid them for the sake of avoidance. I think if you want to improve performance, use something other than the original list (it's not good at random-access as it's a linked list).

Comment: Then unless you'd prefer converting the entire list into a more reasonably accessible collection first, I'd suggest just sticking with your solution. That initialize conversion, depending on how large your list is and how often you need to convert and how often you access different blocks, can definitely improve the performance.

Comment: Can it be written in a simpler way using collections then? I have to write it as simple as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.drop(3 * (block / 3)).take(3).flatMap(_.drop(3 * (block % 3)).take(3)).filter(_ != 0)
```

This is a little more efficient - "zooms" straight into the data you want; sticks with lists all the way through (no conversions).

```
scala> val grid = List(List(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,8),
                       List(0,0,0,2,9,0,5,1,3),
                       List(0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0),
                       List(0,4,0,5,0,0,7,0,2),
                       List(0,0,0,4,6,0,9,8,1),
                       List(3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                       List(0,1,0,5,0,0,4,0,2),
                       List(0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                       List(0,9,0,3,0,0,0,0,2))
grid: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8), List(0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 5, 1, 3), List(0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2), List(0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 9, 8, 1), List(3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2), List(0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2))

scala> def blockElements(block: Int) = grid.drop(3 * (block / 3)).take(3).flatMap(_.drop(3 * (block % 3)).take(3)).filter(_ != 0)
blockElements: (block: Int)List[Int]

scala> blockElements(0)
res1: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> blockElements(5)
res2: List[Int] = List(7, 2, 9, 8, 1)
```

BTW: 9th sub-square has two 4s :).

Comment: Thanks! :) But can you please explain it like what drop and take do exactly

Comment: def drop(n: Int): List[A]
Selects all elements except first n ones.
n the number of elements to drop from this list.
returns  a list consisting of all elements of this list except the first n ones, or else the empty list, if this list has less than n elements.

Comment: if 0<=block<=2 will drop 0 rows; if 3<=block<=5 will drop 1st 3 rows; if 6<=block<=8 will drop 1st 6 rows.  Similarly for columns (if col=0,3,4 will drop 0 cols; if col=1,4,7 will drop 1 col; if col= 2,5,8 will drop 2 cols).

Comment: take is opposite of drop - it *keeps* that many rows/cols and drops the subsequent ones